# java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

Tags: java, database

I am using oracle 11g,hibernate 3 and jsf2.I deployed my application on was7.Every thing is going well but when i try to login after 5-6 hours it is gives me error

```
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Io exception: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
[5/28/13 11:31:25:048 IST] 00000024 SystemErr     R org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2231)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
```

I unable to find out how this error to solve.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Now i have solved this problem by code but i don'nt know is it proper way or not.will you suggest me, i should continue with this solution on not.

```
public class ApplicationUtilityBean implements Serializable {
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private AnnotationConfiguration cfg;
public String filePath;
private String realPath = Config.PATH;

public ApplicationUtilityBean() throws URISyntaxException {
    getConnection();
}

public void getConnection() {
    URL r = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration();
    cfg.configure(r);
    String pwd = cfg.getProperty("hibernate.connection.password");
    TripleDESEncryption tripledesenc = null;
    try {
        tripledesenc = new TripleDESEncryption();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password",
            tripledesenc.decrypt(pwd));
    sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

    System.out.println("cfg: " + cfg);
    System.out.println("sessionFactory: " + sessionFactory);
}

public Session getSession() {
    System.out.println("Going to get session");
    Session session = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("cfg is: " + cfg);
        System.out.println("sessionFactory: " + sessionFactory);
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        if(session != null){
            try {
                Transaction trxn = session.beginTransaction();
                Query queryResult = session.createSQLQuery("select * from dual");
                List<GTS_USER>listgtsuser = queryResult.list();     
                                } catch (Exception e) {                 
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Creating new connection............");
                session.close();
                sessionFactory.close();
                getConnection();
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return session;
}
```

}

and my hibernate config file is

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxxx:1521:HMS</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">xxxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxxxxxxxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property> 
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Comment: Are you specifying the database parameters in hibernate config file or are you using a data source defined in was7 and looked up using JNDI?

Comment: specifying db parameters in hibernate config only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably facing a database connection timeout. On every databases there is a timeout when a connection is open and there is no activity for a certain period. You need a connection pool manager.

If you install `c3p0` and configure it correctly it will allow hibernate to keep your connection alive and/or re-open it when you need it.

Here is an [example](http://crazytechthoughts.blogspot.ca/2011/06/resolve-hibernate-connection-timeout.html) for MySQL and Hibernate indeed but it is the same. You have to include `c3p0.jar` and also add this to your hibernade configuration file :

```
<property name="c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
<property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

Make sure to configure `c3p0.timeout` according to your database!

Comment: I tried the same but its not working. Is there any code level changes also ?

Comment: You are welcome, mark it as answered so other people will know it helped you!

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that an idle connection will be closed by the database server. The application doesn't come to know about it and tries to use a stale connection (from the pool that was created during initialization).  The fix for this is to configure the connection pool to do a test for liveness (usually by firing a simple select query) before using a connection from the pool.

How to do this varies on how you have setup the datasource / connection pooling.  If you provide more details on it I can provide more specific instructions.

Comment: I am just using defoult connection pooling of hibernate 3.I have set proprty in hibernate.cfg.xml.

Answer (score 1):

According to @BalusC

If your application is supposed to run a relatively long time and to connect the DB fairly often, then consider using a connection pool to improve connecting performance. If your application is a webapplication, then take a look in the appserver's documentation, it usually provides a connection pooling facility in flavor of a DataSource. If it is a client application, then look for 3rd party connection pooling libraries which have proven their robustness with years, such as Apache Commons DBCP (commonly used, used in lot appservers), C3P0 (known from Hibernate) and Proxool (if you want XA connections).